# Absolute effect in fixed position

Tags: javascript, html, css

Based on this code:

HTML:

```
<div style="width:1000px;height:1000px;">
    <div id="box1" class="box" style="left:20px;top:20px;">
        My position-x is fixed but position-y is absolute.
    </div>
    <div id="box2" class="box" style="left:20px;top:120px;">
        My position-x is absolute but position-y is fixed.
    </div>
    <div id="box3" class="box" style="left:20px;top:220px;">
        Im positioned fixed on both axis.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box 
{
    width:400px;
    height:80px;
    background:gray;
    position:fixed;  
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
//box one
    var $win = $(window);
    $('#box1').css('top', 20 -$win.scrollTop());
    $('#box2').css('left', 20 -$win.scrollLeft());
});
```

If I give the css directly in css not in the js, how can I still make it work the same way ?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4dWz/)

Comment: Just to be sure, you are trying to get the window location in css?

Comment: yes somehow i want it to be absolute... but with fixed css

Answer (score 0):

*Hate to say it* but it's not possible in plain CSS2,3.

Comment: no not through css through js.. is it not possible through that also ?

Comment: @H_alt I might be missign something, but isn't your jQuery already doing it well? You clearly asked: `how can I still make it work the same way ?`

Comment: its working but the css is defined in the js... I dont want that

Comment: @H_alt (what CSS is defined in JS??) Read my answer again. You cannot set it in CSS and expect it to work the same way. CSS has not `scroll` events.